# Does Grand Theft Auto Online have it's own servers?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, hosting

This question was a bit hard to put into a simple question but basically i'm just wondering if the online section of this game is hosted by Rockstar or if they are hosted locally by the host of each public/private game.

For example is the online set up like an MMORPG where everyone is a client connecting to the server(s). Or is it set up so that players can host games on the server, letting other clients join them meaning clients joining them are subject to the host's internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the servers are not dedicated. But, with that, you can host your own private servers and stuff too. Ping is pretty good in that game, so I wouldn't worry about it too bad.

Comment: Unlike CS:GO... 300+ ping on private matches. :( (Different continents.)